# How to track files in more than one directory in GIT

Tags: git

A Visual FoxPro project includes files that are part of a framework and live in a different directory than the project's working directory.

Despite being part of a framework some of those files are being modified at the same time as the current project evolves, so I would like them to be tracked by the same GIT repository.

How can I tell GIT to do this?

Thank you.

Alex

Comment: Add both the same git repo and push and pull as needed?

Answer (score 0):

[Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) should help you to track framework files.

Comment: Aha. I'll look into it. It may take me some time as I am new to Git.